# Was dynamic type check in Pascal commonplace?

Tags: compilers, pascal, besm-6

The BESM-6 Pascal compiler I'm experimenting with has a notable difference from Standard Pascal: formal arguments of formal parameters-procedures or functions are not specified, but are checked at runtime:

```
 PASCAL COMPILER 15.0 (15.02.82)
 00001    1  0 PROGRAM MAIN(OUTPUT);
 00007    2  1 PROCEDURE P(FUNCTION F:INTEGER);
 00007    3  3 BEGIN
 00015    4  3   WRITELN(F(P));
 00036    5  2 END;
 00037    6  1 FUNCTION F(I:INTEGER):INTEGER;
 00037    7  3 BEGIN
 00045    8  3   F := I + 5
 00045    9  2 END;
 00047   10  2 BEGIN
 00050   11  2   P(F);
 00072   12  0 END.
```

Here we pass an integer function `F` to the procedure `P` and we attempt to call it with a procedure argument, whereas it accepts an integer argument and returns it incremented by 5 (e.g. in case of `WRITELN(F(5))`, `10` would be printed.

The compilation succeeds, and at runtime the following happens:

```
 FORMAL PROC CALL ERROR
 FOR 1 PARAMETR CALL FROM 001032

 PASCAL PM DUMP
      9 STACK LENGTH.  NAME=       P.LINE=3

   3586 STACK LENGTH.  NAME=    MAIN.LINE=12

 PASCAL PMD END
```

I've been able to verify that actual parameters are checked for number and for "severe" type discrepancies. E.g. passing CHAR to a function which accepts INTEGER succeeds, but attempting to pass a procedure instead of an integer fails.

Standard Pascal would not accept the code as written; it requires the formal parameter prototypes to be declared the same way as in actual definitions, like

```
   PROCEDURE P(FUNCTION F(I:INTEGER):INTEGER);
```

and all type checks are done at compile time.

In his book *Systematic Programming: An Introduction*, Wirth provides a syntax diagram

[image: diagram]

and an example

[image: example]

using the syntax accepted by the BESM-6 Pascal compiler. It appears that the  compiler author was following the book quite closely; are there any extant compilers accepting that syntax?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pre-standard" Pascal compilers? Compilers with non-standard additions were common *after* the standard was defined. FWIW early versions of Turbo Pascal dealt with this issue a different non-standard way: procedures and functions could not be passed as parameters.

Comment: @alephzero Pre-ISO 7185:1983.

Comment: Actually, I would think that compile-time type checks would have been much simpler to implement than runtime checks. I don't think they "cut corners" here. At compile time, the compiler needs to have the types on hand anyways. It looks to me as if procedural parameters were an afterthought in the compiler that was added later as a "backpack"

Comment: @tofro Real-world Pascal needs to call procedures and functions not written in Pascal. In general you can't describe the syntax of such calls within the spirit of the Pascal standard (e.g. an external procedure may have variable number of arguments). So for practical purposes, deferring checking till run time, and therefore having no checks on calls to external procedures, is a reasonable compiler design compromise.

Comment: @alephzero: Except that for external procedures in, say, UCSD Pascal, there were **no runtime checks** because no type information was available at runtime (at least in the UCSD p-Code variant I'm familiar with). So it's not a "compiler design compromise", and it doesn't "reduce the size of the compiler at the cost of the speed of the execution"; it just skips the normal Pascal compile-time type checks because for some arguments to external procedures this makes sense.

Comment: Could you list specifically what compilers you'd think of as "pre-standard"? I mean, Nikolaus Wirth invented Pascal, his *Pascal User Manual and Report* from 1974 more or less **became** the standard in 1983. So do you mean pre-1974? Pre-1983, but not following Wirth's definition? Something else? And Wirth definitely was no friend of run-time type checking...

Comment: @alephzero This example is not about *calling external procedures* - It is about *passing (Pascal) procedures as parameters* - these are and need to be well-known at compile time, as the compiler needs to know how to call them - Introspection was not known as a concept back then.

Comment: @dirkt I mean pre-1983, but not following Wirth's definition to the letter. What you're saying, if I understand you correctly, is that run-time type checking, even if it had occurred in more than one implementation, would not have been commonplace. Well, is there at least another one?

Comment: @tofro Compile-time type checks require more complex data structures to represent types; the code to match the types (with varying levels of strictness) recursively, the code to check for errors in all possible contexts and to report them adequately. On platforms with limited RAM this reduces the max size of a compilable program. Conversely, run-time checks require little less than dumping hashes of the type data structures and inserting calls to the library routine which wuld compare them and report an error on mismatch.

Comment: Hmmm. A language that has strong typing like Pascal *must* do compile-time checks anyhow. Otherwise, it's typing isn't really strong. Otherwise, it's simply not Pascal. That's why I assume this to be an afterthought that was added when the compiler core was already done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pascal compilers/runtimes typically do *some* (very often, optionally, enabled by a flag) run-time type checking. A very typical run-time check supported by most Pascal compilers is *array bounds checking*, because it is the most common type-related mismatch error in Pascal programs and bounds of actually used array indices are very hard to check at compile time against actual sizes.

Checking procedural parameters at compile time, on the other hand, is actually relatively easy (or, rather, not conceivably more difficult than what the compiler needs to do anyhow) - Because you can call any procedure or function *directly* (i.e. not across a procedural parameter redirection), it's type and formal parameters must be in some symbol table anyhow - It is relatively easy to check whether such an actual parameter fits the function's formal parameter - If the compiler is cleverly built, that is simply a comparison between two symbol table entries.

Regarding your terminology: In my book, "standard Pascal" is what Wirth published in *Pascal User Manual and Report* - and was later standardized (unchanged in contents, but rather only formalized) as ISO 7185:1983. So, you simply cannot say that there ever was a thing like a "pre-standard Pascal compiler".

If you look at what Wirth provided in terms of implementations, there were actually two: A CDC compiler that supported procedural parameters and a P-code compiler that didn't.

Comment: Any compiler implemented before the ISO standard was adopted in 1983 is pre-standard by definition. As you say, the P-code compilers didn't support procedural parameters; do you know if they had runtime type checks?

Comment: I could not find diagnostics mentioning mismatched parameters in https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/pint.p

Comment: It is now my belief that dynamic type checks were a "feature envy" hack to add support of procedural parameters to a compiler ported using P-series to minimize  disruption to the compiler proper, and to keep its code size to a minimum.

Comment: It appears that the syntax has been taken directly from a Wirth's book. Please see update.