# Was there a bug in Wirth's original Pascal compiler?

Tags: pascal, bugs

It appears that both legacy Pascal compilers I have access to (for the BESM-6) contain a bug: they would happily produce code for

```
program test(output);(* may have to omit (output) depending on the platform *)
function f: integer; (* entering the function sets R2 as the frame pointer *)
begin f := 7 end;    (* assigning 7 to 3(R2) - the value return location *)
begin f := 11 end.   (* assigning 11 to 3(R2), where R2 has not been initialized yet *)
```

Both compilers were derivations from one CDC 6600 version or another, up to the data structures and the order of the subroutines. As the bug is in the machine-independent part, which logic would be transcribed unchanged, I suspect that it would exist in all Pascal implementations derived directly from the same CDC 6600 source by bootstrapping.

**Could anyone please verify that on a CDC 6600 emulator, if one exists, or using a Pascal compiler known to be a port of the original?**

#### JFYI:

Newer Pascal compilers written in C using YACC do error out on the test case above.

[Free Pascal](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-pascal-online/) complains, on line 4, `Error: Argument cannot be assigned to` (why "Argument", though?).

[UCB Pascal on BSD 2.11](https://skn.noip.me/pdp11/pdp11.html) is more lucid, saying `function f found where variable required`.

One other I could find online, [Turbo Pascal](https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/projects/turbo_pascal_compiler/demo/), however, fails with some kind of an internal error: `Error: can't cast from 70 to 76 ("11", line 4)`.

Comment: Compare the source code of the `func` branch of the `selector` routine in the [P2 compiler](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/p2/pcomp.pas) (search for "`IMPL. RELAT. ADDR. OF FCT. RESULT`" to find the relevant line) and in the [P4 compiler](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/book/pcom.html#p2120). In the latter there is an error check complaining if a function name is assigned to outside its body. (In adding the check, an odd `begin`-`end` pair was left, as noted in Daniels and Pemberton's [book about P4](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/book/5expressions.html)).

Comment: The error code displayed by P4 is 177 ("*You may only assign to the identifier of a function in the body of that function*", see https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/book/13appendices.html#errormeanings), which was not included in the list of error codes at the end of the Pascal user manual, so I would propose that the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @texdr.aft I was just a few minutes behind you; having run that experiment myself after spending some time fixing the C source of P4. The high error code was a hint. But it would be instructive to see an independent compiler with the bug in action.

Comment: (1) C source of P4? (2) By independent do you mean not derived from the P series?

Comment: (1) Yes, https://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/pascal/p4c.tar.gz
(2) Right; Although judging by the timeline (the first BESM-6 compiler was released in 1976), they could be based on the P-series rather than the original.

Comment: I found an explanation for the strange Turbo Pascal error: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6573092

Comment: @texdr.aft Thank you! Apparently the hand-written parser of Turbo Pascal was quite deficient. Out of the two compilers I have, one says "semicolon required", pointing to ":="; the other says "no END", mentioning "foo" as the last identifier parsed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the compilers you have were based on the P-series, then I believe that there was indeed a bug.

In the P-series compilers after [P2](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/p2/pcomp.pas), the destination of an assignment is determined by a routine named [`selector`](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/5expressions.html#selector), which branches on the `klass` field of `fcp`, a variable that holds information about a relevant identifier. When the `klass` is `func`, i.e., when the identifier is the name of a function, P2 does this:

```
IF PFDECKIND = STANDARD THEN ERROR(150)
ELSE
  IF PFLEV = 0 THEN ERROR(150)   (*EXTERNAL FCT*)
  ELSE
    IF PFKIND = FORMAL THEN ERROR(151)
    ELSE
      BEGIN ACCESS := DRCT; VLEVEL := PFLEV + 1;
        DPLMT := 0   (*IMPL. RELAT. ADDR. OF FCT. RESULT*)
      END
```

There is an assumption here that an assignment to a function identifier will happen only within the function's body, but no explicit check. In [P4](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/pcom.html#p2114), this bit of code was changed to

```
if pfdeckind = standard then
  begin error(150); typtr := nil end
else
  begin
    if pfkind = formal then error(151)
    else
      if (pflev+1<>level)or(fprocp<>fcp) then error(177);
      begin access := drct; vlevel := pflev + 1;
        dplmt := 0   (*impl. relat. addr. of fct. result*)
      end
  end
```

Here, `pflev` is a field of `fcp`, representing the level of nesting at which `fcp` was declared; `level` is a global variable holding the current depth of nesting; `fprocp` is a parameter of `block`, which is non-`nil` if the block is the body of a function or procedure. Thus the newly-added line ensures that we are (1) in the body of a function and (2) allowed to perform the assignment. Error 177 is new to P4, and means

> You may only assign to the identifier of a function in the body of that function.

There are other early compilers whose source code [survives](http://pascal.hansotten.com/niklaus-wirth/cdc-6000-pascal-compilers/), which were the progenitors of the P-series compilers; none of them, except for the 1984 version, seem to include the check for assignment validity.

---

You might have noticed the strange `begin` and `end` in the P4 excerpt. This was also pointed out [by Pemberton and Daniels](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Esteven/pascal/book/5expressions.html#selector) (the third item in the **Notes** section below). The effect is that code for the assignment is generated, even though it is erroneous; presumably there is an `else` missing.

Comment: [One compiler](https://github.com/besm6/pascal-re/blob/master/pascompl.b6) is most likely based on a P-series compiler or their direct predecessor. After decompilation, some scalar constant names and subroutine names were correlated with a P-series source. The overall code structure matches closely. However, contents of the analog of the "selector" routine (called "parseLval", line 5030) based on relative location and overall function, diverge substantially.

Comment: [The other compiler](https://github.com/besm6/pasauto-re/blob/main/pasauto.pas), not yet restored to good readability, looks much different: there are no individual token scalars; there is just one all-encompassing record type "identifier" for all named objects; expression trees are not constructed, instruction chains for subexpressions are merged during recursive descent, etc.

Comment: I'd like to attract your attention to another question of mine about Pascal implementation specifics: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10976/4025 - here the P-series are of no help as a reference because they do not support procedural parameters at all.

Comment: @LeoB. The best way to answer that question, as well as your previous one about `in`, is probably to go through the "implementation notes" sections of [Pascal Newsletter issues](http://pascal.hansotten.com/pug/).